# Terraform construct a list from map

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform map like below.

```
org_sub_accounts = [
  {
    "id" = "11111111111"
    "type" = "test"
  },
  {
    "id" = "22222222222"
    "type" = "prod"
  },
  {
    "id" = "33333333333"
    "type" = "prod"
  }
 ]
```

I want to create a list from this map by including the account id where the type is `prod`. So the output should be something like the below.

`prod_accounts = ["22222222222","33333333333"]`

Can someone please help? Was trying to figure this out for some time now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `org_sub_accounts` is defined as a `local` (modify answer accordingly if otherwise), then this can be constructed from a `for` expression lambda inside the `list` constructor:

```
[for account in local.org_sub_accounts : account.id if account.type == "prod"]
```

which returns the value:

```
[
  "22222222222",
  "33333333333",
]
```

which can be assigned to a `prod_accounts` as desired. Note this assumes your original structure is a `list(object)` as shown in the question, and therefore always contains the keys `id` and `type`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. And yes, it is defined as local variable for this question. Thanks again.